# How to test function which calls another void function from it with static value as argument using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito

I have a class A as

```
Class A{
 private static final String ANON_DIR             = "/webapps/worldlingo/data/anonymizer/";
 private static final String NO_ANON             = "noanonymize";

  public String first(String text, String srclang, Map dictTokens) {
      Set<String> noAnonymize = new HashSet<String>();
      second(noAnonymize,ANON_DIR + NO_ANON, "tmpLang","name");

      String value;
      if(noAnonymize.contains("test")){
      value = word;
      }
      else {
         value = "test";
        }

    return value;
}
```

where ANON_DIR and NO_ANON is static final value. This class has function first and function second .The first function has a calling method in it which calls second function. The second function is void function which takes static fields as parameter.

Second function is just the file read function with the path provided as

```
private void second (Set<String> hashSet, String path, String lang , String type) {
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
      fr = new FileReader(path);
      br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      String Line;
      while ((Line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        hashSet.add(Line);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Anonymizer: Unable to load file.", e);

    } finally {
      try {
        if (fr != null) {
          fr.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
          br.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Anonymizer : An error occured while closing a resource.", e);
      }
    }
  }

  }
```

Now I am trying to test the function first using mockito. I am trying to change the static parameter and send those changed static parameter as

```
public void testfirst() throws Exception {
    A anon = new A();


    Field ANON_DIR = A.class.getDeclaredField("ANON_DIR");
    ANON_DIR.setAccessible(true);

    //java relection to change private static final field
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(ANON_DIR, ANON_DIR.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    ANON_DIR.set(null,"test");

    Field NO_ANON = A.class.getDeclaredField("NO_ANON");
    NO_ANON.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField1 = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField1.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField1.setInt(NO_ANON, NO_ANON.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    NO_ANON.set(null,"/noanonymize");


    Method anonymizeNames = anon.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("first", String.class, String.class , Map.class);
    String srcLang = "MSFT_EN";
    Map mapTokens = new HashMap();
    String result = (String) anonymizeNames.invoke(anon,"I am David",srcLang,mapTokens);


  }
```

PROBLEM:
  Here I could change the private final static field ANON_DIR and NO_ANON using java reflection but the changed field are not send to the second function. The second function called from first function takes the original value instead of changed value. i.e when the second is called ANON_DIR has
"/webapps/worldlingo/data/anonymizer/" value instead of "test".

Since I changed the value of ANON_DIR to "test" I want the same "test" value to be passed to the second function. How can I acheive this for testing for void second method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the violation of the *Separation of concerns* principle.

Your *code under test* (cut) does too much and thus you have a hard time to find *seams* to replace dependencies.

Also there is a misunderstanding of the aim of unittests. You don't test code, you test *public observable behavior* which is any *return value* and *communication with dependencies* <sub>(but not necessarily public methods)</sub>.

So my suggestion is to move method `second()` to a new class of its own. The cut gets an instance of this new class passed in as *constructor parameter*.
Then it is easy to replace the real dependency with a mock of that new class in your test.

On the other hand you could simple surrender to your bad design by using <strike>PowerMock</strike>...